# Typescript / Javascript - How to avoid duplicated code

Tags: javascript, typescript, dynamodb-queries

I have a piece of code that basically repeats itself.
The only difference is the type of `params` and scan invokes `this.getDbClient().scan(params)` and query invokes `this.getDbClient().query(params)`

```
static scanTable = async (params: DynamoDB.DocumentClient.ScanInput) => {
    let items;
    let scanResults: any[] = [];
    do {
        items = await this.getDbClient().scan(params).promise();
        (items.Items || []).forEach((item) => scanResults.push(item));
        params.ExclusiveStartKey = items.LastEvaluatedKey;
    } while (typeof items.LastEvaluatedKey !== 'undefined');

    return scanResults;
}

static queryTable = async (params: DynamoDB.DocumentClient.QueryInput) => {
    let items;
    let scanResults: any[] = [];
    do {
        items = await this.getDbClient().query(params).promise();
        (items.Items || []).forEach((item) => scanResults.push(item));
        params.ExclusiveStartKey = items.LastEvaluatedKey;
    } while (typeof items.LastEvaluatedKey !== 'undefined');

    return scanResults;
}
```

I tried to extract the function and use

```
async (params: DynamoDB.DocumentClient.ScanInput | DynamoDB.DocumentClient.QueryInput)
```

and then trying to do `instanceof DynamoDB.DocumentClient.ScanInput and instaceof DynamoDB.DocumentClient.QueryInput` but it seems that `instanceof` cannot be used:

> ERROR: Property 'ScanInput' does not exist on type 'typeof DocumentClient'.ts(2339)
>
> ERROR: Property 'QueryInput' does not exist on type 'typeof DocumentClient'.ts(2339)

What can I do here to avoid duplications?

Comment: did you try typeof?

Comment: Using `instanceof` seems fine. Can you show how you used it?

Answer (score 2):

oh the problem is quite simple you can write it like this:

```
static scanTable = async <T extends "scan" | "query", P extends T extends "scan" ? DynamoDB.DocumentClient.ScanInput : DynamoDB.DocumentClient.QueryInput>(type: T, params: P) => {
    let items;
    let scanResults: any[] = [];
    do {
        items = await this.getDbClient()[type](params).promise();
        (items.Items || []).forEach((item) => scanResults.push(item));
        params.ExclusiveStartKey = items.LastEvaluatedKey;
    } while (typeof items.LastEvaluatedKey !== 'undefined');

    return scanResults;
}
```

then use it like this

```
scanTable("scan", <param for scan>)
scanTable("query", <param for query>)
```

Answer (score 0):

here is what you can do :

```
class Table {
  static getTable = async (inputType: 'ScanInput' | 'QueryInput',searchType : 'scan' | 'query') => {
    let documentClient = DynamoDB.DocumentClient[inputType]
    let items;
    let scanResults: any[] = [];
    do {
      items = await this.getDbClient()[searchType](params).promise();
      (items.Items || []).forEach((item) => scanResults.push(item));
      params.ExclusiveStartKey = items.LastEvaluatedKey;
    } while (typeof items.LastEvaluatedKey !== 'undefined');

    return scanResults;
  }
}
```

and use it in this way :

```
Table.getTable('ScanInput','scan')
Table.getTable('QueryInput','query')
```

Answer (score 0):

Tweaking the solution of *@Tachibana Shin*, make it a bit more readable in my opinion, is doing it without the generics, as for this case I don't think generics bring much to the table:

```
type Param = DynamoDB.DocumentClient.ScanInput | DynamoDB.DocumentClient.QueryInput;
type ParamKey = 'scan' | 'query';

static scanTable = async (params: Param, key:ParamKey) => {
    let items;
    let scanResults: any[] = [];
    do {
            items = await this.getDbClient()[key](params).promise();
            (items.Items || []).forEach((item) => scanResults.push(item));
            params.ExclusiveStartKey = items.LastEvaluatedKey;
    } while (typeof items.LastEvaluatedKey !== 'undefined');

    return scanResults;
}
```

!NOTE: regarding `type Param = DynamoDB.DocumentClient.ScanInput | DynamoDB.DocumentClient.QueryInput;` which is based on your example,

be prepared that typescript might marked it with one of the following errors:

```
   XXX refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof XXX'?ts(2749);
```

or

```
Cannot find namespace 'XXX'.ts(2503)
```